# Can I retry a level after the Treasure Yeti has retreated to bring him back?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies-2

When playing a level containing a Treasure Yeti, retrying before the yeti appears does not forfeit your chance to kill the yeti (he still appears in the list of attacking zombies at the outset). However, I've never tried restarting after the yeti has retreated without being killed. **Does retrying after the yeti escapes cause him to show up again?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I *have* retried a level after the Yeti escapes: **no**, it doesn't come back. I was pretty disappointed.

Comment: yea, and on the android version he seems to run away extra fast, sometimes not even reach as far as 1 square in.  super annoying

Comment: @spartacus I think there's both a squares-in trigger and a damage-taken trigger. Doing *too much* damage right away seems to scare it off faster. Try a less-damaging setup, and relying on plant food to kill the yeti.